# "UPDATE" function creates a new line in the MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been experiencing a very peculiar issue since this morning.
When I call the method `modifica()` for 2 times it creates a new empty line in the `utenti` table.

This is where I call it (no loops or anything else):
`if(true===acquista_annuncio($_POST['crediti_annuncio'],$_POST['idmessaggio']))`

This is the function:

```
function acquista_annuncio($crediti_annuncio,$id_annuncio){
global $db;
$dati_tempo_reale=$db->estrai("utenti","email='".$_SESSION['email']."'",NULL,1);

$id_utente=$dati_tempo_reale[0]['id'];
$visualizzazioni_impresa=$dati_tempo_reale[0]['visualizzazioni'];

//Scalare crediti
$crediti_disponibili=crediti_disponibili();
$crediti_utente=$crediti_disponibili-$crediti_annuncio;
$db->inserisci("utenti","crediti","'$crediti_utente'");

//Inserimento ID ditta nella colonna visualizzazioni
$annuncio=$db->estrai("richieste_preventivi","id='$id_annuncio'",NULL,1);
$annuncio=$annuncio[0]['visualizzazioni'];

//Controlla se l'annuncio non è già stato visualizzato dalla stessa ditta, altrimenti restituisce false

if(false===strpos($annuncio,$id_utente)){
    $visualizzazioni_annuncio=$annuncio.",".$id_utente;
    $visualizzazioni_impresa=$visualizzazioni_impresa.",".$id_annuncio;

    $db->modifica("richieste_preventivi","visualizzazioni='$visualizzazioni_annuncio'","id='$id_annuncio'",1);
    $db->modifica("utenti","visualizzazioni='$visualizzazioni_impresa'","id='$id_utente'",1);
    return true;}
else
    { return false; }
}
```

This is the method `modifica` of the $db class.

$this->connessione is the mysqli object.

```
public function modifica($tabella,$campi,$dove,$limite)
    {
    //Esempio: $db->modifica("prova","nome='Elena'","id=1",NULL);
    if(isset($tabella) && isset($campi) && isset($dove))
        {
        $this->query=addslashes(htmlentities("UPDATE ".$tabella)); 
        $this->query.=htmlentities(" SET ".$campi." WHERE ".$dove);

        if(isset($limite))
            $this->query.=addslashes(" LIMIT ".$limite);
        $this->query.=addslashes(";");

        //DEBUG
        echo "console.log(\"$this->query\");";
        if(true===$this->connessione->real_query($this->query))
        return true;
        else
        return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: You're going to want to seperate all these `query.=` to `query .=`

Comment: ^ That alone will break your code ^ - è molto importante ;-) ^

Comment: I'm not understanding.. It works all the times, excepts this...

Comment: What is the solution to fix this?

Comment: I do not know, sorry. I only pointed out the syntax errors for all `query.=` - that need to be changed to `query .=` with the space before the dot.

Comment: I fixed xD It was because this: $db->inserisci("utenti","crediti","'$crediti_utente'");

I was too much focused to this condition:
if(false===strpos($annuncio,$id_utente)){

Comment: benissimo! glad to hear it, thanks for the update, *cheers*